# FileHandler added to Java Logger receives LogRecords twice and doesn't always send output to File when isLoggable returns true

Tags: java, logging, filter, bukkit

My goal with this was to make it so that all `Level.WARNING` and higher `LogRecords` sent to `Bukkit's Logger` were sent to a log file that I've specified, as well as the console (as per usual). I've seen a few web pages showing examples of having multiple handlers for a single Logger and couldn't see how my code differed. I've been messing around with it for a while and can't seem to figure out what is causing the odd behaviour observed in both the console output and file output.

I cause a `NullPointerException` in my `ItemFrameListener` whenever a player right clicks an item frame and expect it to be logged after "TEST" in the file output. The Filter appears to be receiving "TEST" twice and should be returning true each time, but is only logged to file once (which is what I was originally expecting). The first `NPE` returns true the first time, and then false the second time as its hash is now in the set, however nothing is added to the output file. Subsequent NPEs only call the filter once according to the console, returning false each time as expected.

If I add

```
if (true) {
  return true;
}
```

after the initial debug output in LogFilter, then the filter still claims to receive each message twice according to the console output, but does so for all subsequent NPEs after the first, unlike beforehand. "TEST" and both NPEs are recorded in the log file once each in this case (so that's "TEST", NPE1 and NPE2).

If I remove the filter entirely (don't add it in the first place), then all `Level.WARNING` and higher LogRecords make it into the log file (as in the previous test, they only appear once each in the file).

**main plugin class:**

```
package uk.co.mysterymayhem.bukkittestplugin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class BukkitTestPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

  public final GiantDamageListener giantDamageListener = 
          new GiantDamageListener(this);
  public final SpawnerBreakPlaceListener spawnerBreakPlaceListener = 
          new SpawnerBreakPlaceListener(this);
  public final LogBreakListener logBreakListener = new LogBreakListener(this);
  public final ItemFrameListener playerInteractListener = 
          new ItemFrameListener(this);

  @Override
  public void onEnable() {
    PluginManager pm = this.getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(giantDamageListener, this);
    pm.registerEvents(spawnerBreakPlaceListener, this);
    pm.registerEvents(logBreakListener, this);
    pm.registerEvents(playerInteractListener, this);
    try {
      if(!this.getDataFolder().exists()){
        this.getDataFolder().mkdir();
      }
      FileHandler errorHandler = new FileHandler(this.getDataFolder().getPath() + 
              System.getProperty("file.separator") + "errorlog%u.log");
      errorHandler.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
      errorHandler.setFormatter(new java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter());
      errorHandler.setFilter(new LogFilter());
      Bukkit.getLogger().addHandler(errorHandler);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException e) {
      Bukkit.getLogger().info("Error occured adding logging handler");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Enabled testing plugin");
    Bukkit.getLogger().warning("TEST");
  }

  @Override
  public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Disabled testing plugin");
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
  }
}
```

**LogFilter class:**

```
package uk.co.mysterymayhem.bukkittestplugin;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;

public class LogFilter implements Filter {

  private final HashSet<List<Byte>> previousErrors;

  public LogFilter() {
    previousErrors = new HashSet<>();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {

    // Debug message
    Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "{0} [number {1}:{2}]",
            new Object[]{record.toString(), record.getSequenceNumber(),
              record.getLoggerName()});

    // Prepare empty string
    String currentMessage = "";
    try {
      for (StackTraceElement element :
              record.getThrown().getCause().getStackTrace()) {
        currentMessage += element.toString() + "\n";
      }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      // No exception or no exception cause, unlikely to be spammed, so return
      // early
      return true;
    }

    // Prepare List
    List<Byte> currentHashList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      // Create MD5 hash of exception cause
      MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
      byte[] currentHash = digest.digest(currentMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"));

      // Add bytes to Byte list
      for (byte element : currentHash) {
        currentHashList.add(element);
      }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
      // Shh the compiler
    }
    // Try and add this list of Bytes, false if already found, true if new
    // (just return this when working)
    boolean shouldLog = previousErrors.add(currentHashList);
    // Debug output of shouldLog value
    Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "\n\n{0}\n\n", shouldLog);
    return shouldLog;
    //return previousErrors.add(currentHashList);
    //return currentHashList.isEmpty() || previousErrors.add(currentHashList);
  }
}
```

**errorlog0.log contents:**

```
May 29, 2014 7:47:16 AM uk.co.mysterymayhem.bukkittestplugin.BukkitTestPlugin onEnable
WARNING: TEST
```

**server log contents:**

```
[07:47:13] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.7.9
[07:47:13] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: This server is running CraftBukkit version git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks (MC: 1.7.9) (Implementing API version 1.7.9-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Loading WorldEdit v5.6.2
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: [BukkitTestPlugin] Loading BukkitTestPlugin v1
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[07:47:14] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0 (Seed: -3851174208534506511)
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: ----- Bukkit Auto Updater -----
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: It appears that you're running a Development Build, when you've specified in bukkit.yml that you prefer to run Recommended Builds.
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: If you would like to be kept informed about new Development Build releases, it is recommended that you change 'preferred-channel' in your bukkit.yml to 'dev'.
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: With that set, you will be told whenever a new version is available for download, so that you can always keep up to date and secure with the latest fixes.
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: If you would like to disable this warning, simply set 'suggest-channels' to false in bukkit.yml.
[07:47:14] [Thread-7/INFO]: ----- ------------------- -----
[07:47:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 1 (Seed: 6490719194628450682)
[07:47:15] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 2 (Seed: 6490719194628450682)
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Enabling WorldEdit v5.6.2
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: WEPIF: Using the Bukkit Permissions API.
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: [BukkitTestPlugin] Enabling BukkitTestPlugin v1
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Enabled testing plugin
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: java.util.logging.LogRecord@42f0b157 [number 13:Minecraft]
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: java.util.logging.LogRecord@42f0b157 [number 13:Minecraft]
[07:47:16] [Server thread/WARN]: TEST
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[07:47:16] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (1.818s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
[07:47:21] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player Mysteryem is 0e0f6b65-7a4c-4a22-a2cb-3f1437c0a1ae
[07:47:21] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem[/127.0.0.1:63217] logged in with entity id 280 at ([world] 69.6618433079422, 65.51186923562442, 262.1120780933005)
[07:47:23] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem right clicked an item frame
[07:47:23] [Server thread/INFO]: java.util.logging.LogRecord@5fe6b30 [number 18:Minecraft]
[07:47:23] [Server thread/INFO]: 

true


[07:47:23] [Server thread/INFO]: java.util.logging.LogRecord@5fe6b30 [number 18:Minecraft]
[07:47:23] [Server thread/INFO]: 

false


[07:47:23] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEntityEvent to BukkitTestPlugin v1
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:294) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:501) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:486) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1071) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.a(SourceFile:55) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.handle(SourceFile:10) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:157) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:134) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:667) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:260) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:558) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:469) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uk.co.mysterymayhem.bukkittestplugin.ItemFrameListener.onPlayerrightClick(ItemFrameListener.java:61) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:292) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    ... 13 more
[07:47:24] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem right clicked an item frame
[07:47:24] [Server thread/INFO]: java.util.logging.LogRecord@286863e6 [number 24:Minecraft]
[07:47:24] [Server thread/INFO]: 

false


[07:47:24] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerInteractEntityEvent to BukkitTestPlugin v1
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:294) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:501) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:486) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1071) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.a(SourceFile:55) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.handle(SourceFile:10) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:157) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ServerConnection.c(SourceFile:134) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.v(MinecraftServer.java:667) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:260) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:558) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:469) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R3.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at uk.co.mysterymayhem.bukkittestplugin.ItemFrameListener.onPlayerrightClick(ItemFrameListener.java:61) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_51]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:292) ~[craftbukkit-1.7.9-R0.1-20140503.225437-20.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-66-g43d8943-b3078jnks]
    ... 13 more
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem issued server command: /stop
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem: Stopping the server..[m
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: [BukkitTestPlugin] Disabling BukkitTestPlugin v1
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Disabled testing plugin
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: [WorldEdit] Disabling WorldEdit v5.6.2
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem lost connection: Server closed
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Mysteryem left the game.
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[07:47:27] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/Overworld
[07:47:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world_nether'/Nether
[07:47:28] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world_the_end'/The End
[07:47:28] [Thread-4/INFO]: Stopping server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send output from one logging framework to another you should create a custom [Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html).

Using a logger in the LogFilter can create a [logging loop](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4939307).  The logging framework is **not** designed to handle this.  You have to remove all use of the logger inside of the Filter class.  If you want to trace the output you should create a custom Formatter.  Then install it on the FileHandler.

```
public class TraceFormatter extends SimpleFormatter {

@Override
public String format(LogRecord record) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    LogRecord trace = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "{0} [number {1}:{2}]");
    trace.setSourceClassName(record.getSourceClassName());
    trace.setSourceMethodName(record.getSourceMethodName());
    trace.setLoggerName(record.getLoggerName());
    trace.setParameters(new Object[]{record.toString(), 
        record.getSequenceNumber(),
          record.getLoggerName()});

    buf.append(super.format(trace)).append('\n');
    //Insert more code.
    buf.append(super.format(record));

    return buf.toString();
}
```

}

Another thing to keep in mind is that any throwable that escapes 'Filter.isLoggable(LogRecord)' is **not** captured by an [ErrorManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/ErrorManager.html).  You might want to capture errors so they don't leak into your program.

```
public class LogFilter implements Filter {
private final ErrorManager error = new ErrorManager();

@Override
public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
    try {
        //Insert code.
        return false;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        error.error(new SimpleFormatter().format(record), 
                re, ErrorManager.GENERIC_FAILURE);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As I have specified the level of the handler to **Level.WARNING**, shouldn't the **Level.INFO** logs inside the LogFilter not be passed to my handler, therefore preventing a loop? Trying your suggestion produced a single **Level.INFO** LogRecord for the **Level.WARNING** "TEST" in the output file. Still not managing to produce output from the NPE.

Comment: Yes and no.  The level just controls if publish will format.  The code will still make a reentrant call to Handler.publish no matter what the level is set to.  This means that half of the entry calls to logger.log don't hold any downstream lock and the other half hold a handler lock.  That can be a landmine.  I'll edit my answer to address the NPE question.